# PTIJ in a year with Purim Meshulash

Tags: discussion, purim-torah-policy

In some years, Shushan Purim (15 Adar) falls on Shabbat, as with 2008/5768 and 2021/5781. In such a case, Those cities which observe Shushan Purim will extend the festivities over three days.

In those years, should we permit Purim Torah questions to be asked throughout Purim Meshulash, rather than closing them after Shushan Purim?

Comment: I'd have to check http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/797/revisions against a calendar (which I'm not doing at the moment), but I'm pretty sure we've allowed questions through the 16th of each _Adar (sheni)_ anyway.

Comment: @msh210, would we somehow note P"M in the Purim Torah opening for the year?

Comment: @msh210, so I guess the question is whether on Meshulash years, the 17th should be included, too, as a grace period. (And come, to think of it, maybe on years, like this one, when the 16th is Shabbat.)

Comment: @IsaacMoses, something along those lines, although hopefully we get more thoughts on this over time.

Answer (score 5):

Proposal: people *who observe Shushan Purim* get the extra day to ask questions.  The rest of us should have moved on to cleaning for Pesach.  (While questions remain open anybody can answer.)

As a practical matter, though, I believe there's been some variation in the exact dates from year to year, in part to accommodate Shabbat, and it would be very un-PTIJ-like to take this too seriously.  Something resembling consensus, or at least lack of strenuous objections ("here, have another drink!"), can be reached each year.

Comment: Agreed! Shavua tov